# Facing issue while calling a WCF webservice (under HTTPS) from VBS file

Tags: wcf, vbscript

I have created a WCF WebService having multiple svc files. I call the method in the svc file from vbscript using below code:

```
ScriptTimeOut = 6000000

Dim soapServer, soapMessage

soapServer = "https://example.com/marketyardwebservice/SchedulerClasses/MailIntimations.svc"

soapMessage = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=" & GetQuotedUrl("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/") & ">" & _ 
"<s:body>" & _ 
"<AuctionWinnerSendMail xmlns=" & GetQuotedUrl("http://tempuri.org/") & ">" & _
""

soapMessage = Replace(soapMessage, "'", chr(34))

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

xmlhttp.SetOption 2, xmlhttp.GetOption(2) 
Dim lResolve,lConnect,lSend,lReceive
lResolve = 5 * 1000
lConnect = 60 * 1000
lSend = 600 * 1000
lReceive = 600 * 1000

xmlhttp.setTimeouts lResolve, lConnect, lSend, lReceive

xmlhttp.open "POST", soapServer, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Man", POST & " " & soapServer & " HTTP/1.1"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IMailIntimations/AuctionWinnerSendMail"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"

xmlhttp.send(soapMessage)

Function GetQuotedUrl(ByVal value)
    GetQuotedUrl = Chr(34) & value & Chr(34)
End Function
```

The above script gets executed properly when https is not enabled. But as soon as I enable HTTPS, I am getting the following error when the vbscript gets executed "**A certificate is required to complete client authentication**".

Please can anybody help me, as to how i can resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you enable HTTPS on your server set Client Certificates to `Ignore`.